# Convert img tag to display FontAwesome icon

Tags: html, css

I have a third party product which outputs an icon via an `<img>` tag with a background-image set via css.

I could probably write some javascript to change the html tag itself to something different but I would rather change the css to display a FontAwesome icon using the `:before` and `content="{FontAwesomeText}"`.

However, I cant get this to work...does someone know if this is possible to do this?

Please see

```
.x-tree-icon-leaf:before {
    content: "";
    font-size: 0.6em;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
}

.x-tree-icon-leaf {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #5fa2dd;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uz9q6m33/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your jsFiddle did not properly import the FontAwesome library.
2. You can't just copy paste the character and place it inside `content`, you need the proper unicode value of that specific icon, which is: `\f06c`
3. `img` cannot have pseudo elements, use a classed sibling or parent for the icon and hide the image with `display: none`.

**Working code:**

```css
.x-tree-icon-leaf, .x-tree-icon-text::before {
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 "FontAwesome";
  display: inline-block;
  color: #5fa2dd;
}

.x-tree-icon-leaf::before, .x-tree-icon-text::before {
    content: "\f06c\00a0";
    font-size: 1em;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}

img.x-tree-icon-leaf { display: none; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- working with normal span -->
<div> <span class="x-tree-icon-leaf"></span> <span>Hello</span> </div>

<!-- hiding image then applying icon to text-span -->
<div> <img class="x-tree-icon-leaf"> <span class="x-tree-icon-text">Hello</span> </div>
```

jsFiddle fork: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/1y3jwnsg/

**Note:** Add `\00a0` at the end of `content:''` string to force a space for consistency.

The icon is applied to `x-tree-icon-leaf` and `x-tree-icon-text` at the same time. When `x-tree-icon-leaf` is an `img` tag, it will be hidden.

Comment: Hi...when i setup the FontAwesome as an external reference it was working.  Apologies if this is no longer the case.

However, the issue wasnt the first span (as I had this working) it is the <img> tag as written in the OP which Im trying to display the FontAwesome content :)

Comment: Also must apologise somebody had proposed new workding on my OP and some of the important text had been removed.... which why it was not clear thatit was the "img" tag I was trying to rectify.  I htink I have updated the post...Thanks

Comment: @GlenHong you want to replace an `img` with your icon? `img` is a self-closing tag and cannot have pseudo elements.. is there a classed sibling or parent to that image which can be manipulated instead while hiding the image with `display:none;`?

Comment: Yes please see the updated fiddle.... there is actually a span next to the image with a class name on it....

https://jsfiddle.net/kb46jt0p/

Comment: Thank you your suggestion has worked...If you post a new simple answer stating just to hide the img background and place css on the sibling to display the fontawesome logic i will approve that!  thanks!